# Get id of element with class .waypoint when it hits top of screen on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a nav bar with a bunch of links that scroll the window to various anchors (or waypoints) on the page.  What I additionally need is when the window is manually scrolled, I would like to toggle the class of the links in the nav bar (to .active) based on what waypoint hits the top of the screen.  My waypoints are basically as follows:

`<span class="waypoint" id="link1"></span>`

I'm currently using jQuery for this.

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using this ?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: This is perfect thank you.  But thanks also to mplungjan for his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ptzUV/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var waypoint = $(".waypoint").not(".seen").first();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    // change to active 0-10 pixels 
    if (scrollTop >= waypoint.offset().top && scrollTop <= waypoint.offset().top+10) {
        waypoint.addClass("active");
    }
    if (scrollTop > waypoint.offset().top+10) {
        waypoint.addClass("seen");
        waypoint.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks.  But what I'd like is for the nav link to have the active class.  Sorry, maybe I didn't explain it properly.  So maybe if whichever nav link had an anchor that was the same as the ID that was currently at the top of the screen or being scrolled over.  That active class would need to remain until another waypoint is scrolled over.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Hmm, something like adding `$(".seen").removeClass("active")` in the top if and removing the `waypoint.removeClass("active");` in the second if